# timer exit condition in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

```
                 String move=jTextField1.getText();             
                 i=Integer.parseInt(move);
                 timer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        i--;
                        if(i<=0)
                        {
                                if(move.equals("0"))
                                {
                                    Thread th=new Thread(new DetectImage());
                                    th.start();
                                   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                new TrafficMainGUI(storeValue);
                            }
                                   });

                                }

        timer.stop();
                        }
                        }
                        jTextField1.setText(""+i);
                    }
                 });
                    timer.start();

           move=""+i;



//Thread th in DetectImage class
 public void run()
    {
        while(stay<20)
        {
            try {
                stay++;
    //few contions
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
       }
  }
```

//EveryThing is working fine with thread but when i use SwingUtiities.invokeLater()
to call the same class in which this code is there for getting infinite condition.
This doesnot redirect it to the class TrafficMainGUI.Is there some other method to achieve this kind of model.

Comment: Yours is a Swing application and so you should not be using a Java.util.Timer but rather a javax.swing.Timer also known as a "Swing Timer". Sorry to say, but you must re-write this section of your code, else there is a great risk that your code will violate Swing threading rules. If you still get stuck then please again show your code and perhaps give a little more background detail on your problem.

Comment: instead of Timer use Thread class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `jTextField1.setText(""+i)`; must be wrapped in `invokeLater` for this job by invoked from `util.Timer`
2. use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead
3. `if(move.equals("0")) {` is about animations, then to use `Swing Timer` exclusivelly

Comment: use Swing Timer for second part too, Thread.sleep(int) freeze your whatever, but for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: i have edited this post and want swingutilities.invokelater() to call again the same class.So that all threads could again initialze.